# Test a parameter inside a mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, parameters

I want to avoid to write conditional statements to check parameters before query my database
so that i don't have to write multiple times the similar query but i have to write one single query.

**So my first query is**

```
db.results.find( {  travel_class : "first" } })
```

**and returns several documents**

**my second query is**

```
var travel_class_filter = "all";
db.results.find( {'$and' : [ { travel_class_filter : "all"} , { travel_class : "first" } ]})
```

**and returns 0 document instead of the same number of documents of the second query**

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a query depending on 1 parameter named travel_class_filter. If this parameter is set to 'all' , I don't want to filter on travel_class column. So I want to write a single query instead of something like " if (travel_class_filter == 'all') { db.results.find( { })} else { db.results.find( {  travel_class : travel_class_filter } }) }  SO  I think my query should be :  db.results.find( {'$or' : [ { travel_class_filter : "all"} , { travel_class : travel_class_filter } ]}) but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't test parameters as part of your query, but you can do this by building up your query object programmatically:

```js
var query = {};
if (travel_class_filter != 'all') {
    query.travel_class = travel_class_filter;
}
db.results.find(query);
```